# How can i make to get not only by id but by one more column also

Tags: php, codeigniter, web

this my

**model**

```
public function get_news($NewsId= FALSE)
    {
        if ($NewsId === FALSE)
        {
         $this->db->select('*');
         $this->db->from('news');
         $this->db->where('Status' , 1);
         $this->db->where('Language' , 2);

        return $query->result_array();
        $config['per_page']; $this->uri->segment(3);
        }
        $query = $this->db->get_where('news', array('NewsId' => $NewsId));
        return $query->row_array();
```

**controller**

```
public function single($NewsId)
        {

        $data['news_item'] = $this->news_model->get_news($NewsId);
        if (empty($data['news_item']))
        {
        show_404();
        }
        $data['NewsId'] = $data['news_item']['NewsId'];

        $this->load->view('news/single', $data);

        }
```

**view**

```
<?php echo $news_item['TittleNews'];?>
```

i have other view that foreach all my news table and i want create read more the i have created on up my code it works fine 
**want to make read more with NewsId and one other column it mean first check the NewsId and then other colum and then show me on my view which is singly**

Comment: please tell us clearly what you want. With that English i am unable to understand what you mean

Comment: Im sorry, But your requirement is not very clear to me.

Comment: @rafiq problem is your question title has nothing to do with the question content, can't catch you really :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a model method like this:

```
 function getBy($data){
    foreach($data as $key=>$value){
      $this->db->where($key,$value);
    }

    $query = $this->db->get('users_table');
    return $query->row(); //or $query->result(); as you want
  }
```

so then you call it with

```
$this->model->getBy(
array(
'username'=>'Mark',
'id'=>'90',
'email'=>'asd@asd.com'
);
);
```

obviously you can then extend the model method as much as you can